# Multiclass predictions with a categorical_crossentropy loss

Tags: python-3.x, keras

Let's say this example implements a simple binary classification.

> X = array([[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[3,4,5]])
>
> y = array([0],[1],[0])

```
...
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')
model.fit(X, y, epochs=50, verbose=0)
# new instance where we do not know the answer
Xnew = array([[4, 5, 6]])
# make a prediction
ynew = model.predict(Xnew)
#show the inputs and predicted outputs
print("X=%s, Predicted=%s" % (Xnew[0], ynew[0]))
...

results
X=[4, 5, 6], Predicted=[0 or 1]
```

And  this one implements multiclass classification.

> X = array([[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[3,4,5]])
>
> y = array([4],[5],[6])

```
...

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')
# fit model
model.fit(X, y, epochs=50, verbose=2)
model.reset_states()
# evaluate model on new data
yhat = model.predict((X))
...

results decoded
X=[4, 5, 6], Predicted=[4, 5, 6]
```

How to implement multiclass classification with single output to get something like this? (similar to forecasting time series)

> X = array([[1,2,3],[2,3,4],[3,4,5]])
>
> y = array([4],[5],[6])

```
 # new instance where we do not know the answer
 Xnew = array([[4, 5, 6]])
 yhat = model.predict_classes(Xnew)
```

> results decoded
>   X=[4, 5, 6], Predicted=[7]

Comment: In your example `7` is not in your training data. Is this a possibility? In which case your choice of model will never give this answer. You'll need an entirely different model (e.g. one for time series). Alternatively, you could try transform the problem (e.g. one that predicts the increase from the previous time step... not sure how helpful that would be though without another example)

Comment: @nick `7` is finite  number of classes, it can be also `3` or `4`. The main question is possibility and/or implementation of more than 2 choices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is the `loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy'` function which will assume that the integer targets are class labels. So if your model has 7 outputs, and you give target 2, `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` will convert 2 into `[0,0,1,0,0,0,0]` as the target and apply `categorical_crossentropy` as usual.

In this case, your output layer activation function should be `softmax` and number of outputs be equal to the number of classes. Most likely something like `Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax')`

If your integer classes are just `[4,5,6]` then you need to shift them to `[0,1,2]` to satisfy the condition `max(Y_targets) < num_classes`.

Comment: Thank you, `shifting  targets`, That's what I missed.